# What do "RIC" and "RE" on Armenian passport stamps mean?

Tags: terminology, passport-stamps, turkish-citizens, armenia, israeli-citizens

I'm a Turkish student studying in Armenia and while we were crossing the land border with my Israeli friend, no one else but us got these abbreviations (I guess) written on our passport stamps (and we were a large group of people with many different nationalities). Knowing that the relationship between Turkey & Israel, and Armenia is not super nice, I assumed it may have something to do with that. :)

[image]

[image]

All Bagratashen – Sadakhlo land border. On the top, enter into Armenia, bottom left leaving Armenia, bottom right entering Armenia again (we had to leave-enter-leave Armenia in an hour due to luggage problems).

Comment: It might not be RIC and RE, but R/C on the right and RC on the left, where the C has a bit of a whorl to it (I used to write like that, before typing took away my ability to write legibly.)

Comment: @pnuts True, I have residence card, but none of our friends –who also have residentship– has this written (but in contrast, all of my Turkish friends got it). =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I dared to ask the officer while leaving the country and he said it is "RC - Residence Card". I still don't know why only some people got it written but that is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, all three are definitely RC just 3 different penmanship styles.   This can be written for numerous reasons,but the one that I am most familiar with is when its under the H&C reasoning.  (Humanitarian and Compassionate)  Basically refugee.  As for the others, I am not sure.  I know this did not answer your question completely, but hopefully it cleared up that it is definitely RC that you are trying to figure out the meaning for, so that should help you narrow your search down.  Also, I am not sure on the relationship between turkey and armenia regarding refugees and what qualifies as a refugee.